# What does the graph of a $\Delta y$ vs $(t-\frac{1}{2}t_f)^2$ tell you?

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics

I was doing a lab and in one of the steps it asked to construct a $\Delta y$ vs $(t-\frac{1}{2}t_f)^2$ graph from the data I had collected. I don't really understand what the $(t-\frac{1}{2}t_f)^2$ tells you. It's a projectile motion lab in which we had to collect different information of a puck's motion on an air table. It is supposed to be a simulation of a projectile falling in a parabolic motion.

Comment: Could you tell exactly what the experiment is and what $\Delta y$ and $t_f$ are? Also, if $t$ it time, the expression $t-1$ tells me that you are using some kind of dimensionless time units (which sometimes can be ok).

Comment: Just to reiterate the comment above: We can't help if you don't tell us what the variables are. If you're unsure perhaps you could give us an outline of your experiment and how you got the value of \frac{t-1}{2tf}, did you directly measure t and f? If so tell us how.

Comment: Ok. So you are supposed to record the displacement in the x and y direction of a puck travelling on an air table every 0.1 seconds. T is in fact time and d is displacement. Tf is final time. And this edit is not correct. It asks for (t-(tf/2))^2.

Comment: @A.AK Still unclear. I understand you should graph the displacement in $y$-direction (correct?), but what is the actual experiment? If I just put a puck on an air table, not much is going to happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having much information (what experiment, meaning of parameters...), I can only answer your question generally. Perhaps it is useful to you.

If you have a physical quantity for which you know (from theory) the relationship of this quantity on some parameter. And let's say this relationship is a somewhat complicated mathematical function (anything more complicated than linear).

Then if you measure this physical quantity vs the parameter you will get an equally ugly/complicated set of data points. It will be difficult to tell from the plot whether the data corresponds to the expected theoretical relationship or is some other complicated relationship.

If on the other hand you do not plot the physical quantity vs parameter directly, but plot some function of the physical quantity vs some function of the parameter such that the relationship between these two functions is simple (often linear), you will get a simple, easy to understand plot and can immediately tell from the plot whether the data matches the theory. Also often you can directly extract additional information from the plot (e.g. from the slope of linear segments or from where the graph cuts through the axis).

**Example**

Let's say you do an experiment to prove Boyle's law ($P\propto 1/V$), i.e. you take a closed container of gas where you can measure the pressure as a function of volume keeping the temperature constant. Then if you plot the pressure vs the volume you get graphs like on the left in the following picture.

[image]

From the graphs/data in this $P$ vs $V$ plot you cannot tell easily what the relationship between pressure and volume is. It could be for instance a $P\propto 1/V^2$ relationship.

However if you instead plot $P$ vs $1/V$ you get a nice linear relationship telling you immediately that $P\propto 1/V$ and also the slope of the lines is directly related to the temperature of the gas.

Note that this is not the only way to get straight lines as you can see in the following diagrams:

[image]